# Difficulty in Installing GraphLab for python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie in Machine learning and want to build a recommendation system for my class project. To do so, I need to work with GraphLab. But I cannot find any version of it which will be supported by python 3.5.2. The latest available version is 2.1, which is supported by python 2.7x. Is there any equivalent package of GraphLab, or any alternative ways to build this system?

Comment: You can install it using easy install after running `2to3` on the entire package.

Comment: Thanks ,i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no stable release of GraphLab for python 3.5. They are working on a stable release. However, there were a beta release [here](https://static.turi.com/products/graphlab-create/2.0.1/python3.5/windows/GraphLab_Create-2.0.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl#_ga=2.92282905.520229832.1511379665-2014065588.1511379665) for 3.5 which seems to be inaccessible right now. You may try out [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), [H2O](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html#) as alternative.They have support for 3.5.